# How to grant service account access to a user account on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

I have a problem with `gcloud` command and spends a week how to fix.
When I ran gcloud command `gcloud auth revoke`, I get the following error.

```
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [xxx@gmail.com]. // xxx@gmail.com is my user account which is the owner of the project.
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.create) Failed to impersonate [xxx@gmail.com]. Make sure the account that's trying to impersonate it has access to the service account itself and the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role.
```

To fix this, I created a service account which has "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role and grant the policy to xxx@gmail.com. But it it does not work.

The detailed error is below (ran the command with "--log-http").

```
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
method: POST
== headers start ==
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-cloud-sdk gcloud/310.0.0 command/gcloud.auth.revoke invocation-id/xxx environment/None environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/2.7.16 term/xterm-256color (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 19.2.0)
== headers end ==
== body start ==
Body redacted: Contains oauth token. Set log_http_redact_token property to false to print the body of this request.
== body end ==
==== request end ====
---- response start ----
status: 200
-- headers start --
-content-encoding: gzip
alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-length: 1389
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 22 Nov 2020 00:59:28 GMT
expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 0
-- headers end --
-- body start --
Body redacted: Contains oauth token. Set log_http_redact_token property to false to print the body of this response.
-- body end --
total round trip time (request+response): 0.207 secs
---- response end ----
----------------------
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/xxx@gmail.com:generateAccessToken
method: POST
== headers start ==
Content-Type: application/json
authorization: Bearer xxx
user-agent: google-cloud-sdk gcloud/310.0.0 command/gcloud.auth.revoke invocation-id/xxx environment/None environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/2.7.16 term/xterm-256color (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 19.2.0)
== headers end ==
== body start ==
Body redacted: Contains oauth token. Set log_http_redact_token property to false to print the body of this request.
== body end ==
==== request end ====
---- response start ----
status: 404
-- headers start --
-content-encoding: gzip
alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: private
content-length: 114
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 22 Nov 2020 00:59:28 GMT
server: ESF
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 0
-- headers end --
-- body start --
Body redacted: Contains oauth token. Set log_http_redact_token property to false to print the body of this response.
-- body end --
total round trip time (request+response): 0.389 secs
---- response end ----
----------------------
```

Another thing it makes me confused is `gcloud auth revoke` does not work, but `gcloud auth login` and `gcloud auth list` works without any errors.

If anyone had faced this issue and knows how to solve this, I would like to know how. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that I set my user account as impersonated service account which does not make any sense.

After I ran `gcloud config unset auth/impersonate_service_account`, it works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for adding response to your own answer! Please consider marking it as correct to help others.